# pass variable from one function to another one

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to pass my variable "fullname" in my next function?

First function:

```
function chatWith(chatuser,fullname) {    
    createChatBox(fullname);     
    createChatBox(chatuser);      
    $("#chatbox_"+chatuser+" .chatboxtextarea").focus();    
}
```

Second function, where I want to grab the "fullname" variable:

```
function createChatBox(chatboxtitle,minimizeChatBox) {   
    var fname= fullname;    
}
```

Comment: Please correct you question, is not visible what is source code, and what question...

Comment: You might find this article helpful: [Functions @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions)

Answer (score 1):

Your function

```
function createChatBox(chatboxtitle,minimizeChatBox)
```

expects 2 parameters: chatboxtitle and minimizeChatBox.

Now because you call the function like this:

```
createChatBox(fullname);
```

inside your function the *fullname* will be available as the first parameter *chatboxtitle*

```
var fname= chatboxtitle;
```

Like mentioned by @showdev you should probably [read about Functions on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) or [see some examples at w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp).

Answer (score 1):

When you're learning object oriented programming, you need to get comfortable with the concept and idea of "scope". Basically, your name is `wenhenster` and let's say you live in New York City. Now if someone wanted to call you, they'd have to know which `wenhenster` you are. You are the one in New York City. However, let's say there's another `wenhenster` who lives in Los Angeles. How is anyone supposed to know which `wenhenster` you are, unless you define where you live. You live in New York. The same concept works with OOP. If you have:

```
function new_york(){

}
```

And I define, your name within that function:

```
function new_york(){
var wenhenster = "one cool person who lives in New York";
}
```

Javascript knows that there is a `wenhenster` in the `new_york` function. If you have another function titled `los_angeles`:

```
function los_angeles(){

}
```

And you try to use `wenhenster` within the `los_angeles` function,

```
function los_angeles(){
wenhenster += ", but now lives in Los Angeles";
}
```

Javascript doesn't have a clue what you're talking about because within `los_angeles` there's nothing defined or passed to it. You could approach this at least two different ways: define a 'global' `wenhenster` that can be used from within each function, or you can pass the `wenhenster` variable from function to function.

1st Approach:

```
var wenhenster = "one cool person";
function new_york(){
wenhenster += " lives in New York";
}
function los_angeles(){
wenhenster += ", but now lives in Los Angeles";
}
new_york();
los_angeles();
alert(wenhenster); //to view the result
```

Your result would be:

```
"one cool person lives in New York, but now lives in Los Angeles"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oppe5b05/

2nd Approach:

```
function new_york(){
var wenhenster = "one cool person lives in New York";
wenhenster = los_angeles(wenhenster);
alert(wenhenster); //to view the result
}
function los_angeles(name){
name += ", but now lives in Los Angeles";
return name;
}
new_york();
```

Your result would be:

```
"one cool person lives in New York, but now lives in Los Angeles"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fewh5f2d/

Hope that helps. It may be an abstract example, but the more you practice the easier it will become.